# Extract every 3 column from a df to a list of df-s

Tags: r, dataframe, loops

I would like to make a loop that extracts every 3 column from my dataframe. The original dataframe length is not fix, so it could be 30 column or 12 long. The only thing what is fix that there will be 3 columns after each other I want to extract and put it into a list of dataframes.

For example:

```
KO5_1    KO5_2     KO5_3    KO9_1
1        1         3        3
2        0         0        3
2        2         3        0
0        0         1        2
```

and I want the KO5_1 KO5_2 KO5_3 to be extracted and put together in a separate df. The KO9 and the other 2 of its kind will go another df. The names are changing its just an example.

How can I make this loop?

Thank you!

Comment: `split.default(df, seq_len(ncol(df)-1) %/% 3 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `split.default`, with `gl(n, 3)` to split every three columns. Or `gl(3, 1)` if you wanna get three groups of one column every three columns.

```r
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(10, sample(5)))
names(df) <- paste0("K0", 1:10)

n = ceiling(ncol(df) / 3)
split.default(df, gl(n, 3))
```

```
$`1`
  K01 K02 K03
1   2   3   3
2   4   1   5
3   3   2   2
4   1   5   1
5   5   4   4

$`2`
  K04 K05 K06
1   5   4   4
2   4   3   2
3   2   5   1
4   3   2   3
5   1   1   5

$`3`
  K07 K08 K09
1   3   4   1
2   5   5   3
3   1   1   2
4   4   3   5
5   2   2   4

$`4`
  K010
1    3
2    5
3    1
4    4
5    2
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's use a sample data frame. The names aren't important.

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(replicate(10, sample(5)))

df
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 1  1  5  3  2  1  1  2  1  2   4
#> 2  4  3  5  5  3  2  5  4  5   2
#> 3  3  4  1  4  5  5  1  3  3   1
#> 4  5  2  4  3  4  3  4  2  4   3
#> 5  2  1  2  1  2  4  3  5  1   5
```

To get this into a list of 3 data frames comprising every 3rd column, we can do:

```r
n <- 3

lapply(seq(n) %% n, function(i) df[seq_along(df) %% n == i])
#> [[1]]
#>   V1 V4 V7 V10
#> 1  1  2  2   4
#> 2  4  5  5   2
#> 3  3  4  1   1
#> 4  5  3  4   3
#> 5  2  1  3   5
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   V2 V5 V8
#> 1  5  1  1
#> 2  3  3  4
#> 3  4  5  3
#> 4  2  4  2
#> 5  1  2  5
#>
#> [[3]]
#>   V3 V6 V9
#> 1  3  1  2
#> 2  5  2  5
#> 3  1  5  3
#> 4  4  3  4
#> 5  2  4  1
```

You can change `n` to get every 4th column, 5th column, etc.

Comment: I think the expected output should be V1 V2 V3 in a df, V4 V5 V6 in another, etc

Comment: Oh, you're probably right @Maël - I think I was thrown by the naming of the columns. Great use of `gl` in your answer. +1